# How to use the correct SSH private key?

Tags: linux, ssh, private-key

I have a private key inside /home/myuser/.ssh/privateKey

I have a problem connecting to the ssh server, because i always get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I tried to debug the problem and i find that ssh is reading wrong file, take a look at the output:

```
[damiano@Damiano-PC .ssh]$ ssh -v root@vps1 
OpenSSH_5.8p2, OpenSSL 1.0.0g-fips 18 Jan 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for vps1
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 111.111.111.111 [111.111.111.111] port 2000.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/damiano/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/damiano/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/damiano/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/damiano/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 74:8f:87:fe:b8:25:85:02:d4:b6:5e:03:08:d0:9f:4e
debug1: Host '[111.111.111.111]:2000' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/damiano/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/damiano/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/damiano/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

as you can see ssh is trying to read: `/home/damiano/.ssh/id_rsa` but i don't have this file, i named it differently. How could I tell to SSH to use the correct private key file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override this with a personal config file and point to your keyfile;

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
```

And then you can append the following;

```
Host vps1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privateKey
```

Tip: I usually have to following set before any host declaration, it will try your default key first, then it will look in the folder ~/.ssh/$hostname/$userid and finally in ~/.ssh/$hostname;

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%h/%r/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%h/%r/id_dsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%h/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%h/id_dsa
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use:

```
ssh -i <Key file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after setting the options suggested by Mark, I also had to set `IdentitiesOnly yes` to make sure ONLY the specified key was used.